# Django/ nginx Production | Images are not being found on server

Tags: python, django, nginx, deployment, ufw

I have deployed a django project to a linux server i have hosted.

I am using:
django
python
nginx
ufw

My project is deployed and is displaying online but my images are not being found.
I have given the nginx files my project path etc. but still no luck, please could you suggest any ideas ?
I have googled and everything but now luck. (I am new to the deployment world)

I have tried adding location /static/ into the nginx files.
I have tried chatgpt.
I have tried looking for the static folder and it does exist with the images in it.

Comment: So your application is reachable, everything is working fine, except that images do not load on the whole webpage, is that correct? How do you start your django server?

Comment: Hi Geilmaker,
Yes - that is correct.

Everything is reachable, but the images don't load when the django app debug option is set to False, so when it is in debug mode, it works perfectly, but not when not in debug mode.

I have also tried the collectstatic command but that did not work.

Comment: Can we see the nginx configuration file for that webpage?

Comment: My server just lost connection - once it is back up i will.